# neovim clangd setup not able to detect sub header files

Tags: c++, neovim, clangd, neovim-plugin

The setup with clangd on neovim works fine for c++, but found it does not work in this case:
File A.h if has #include "A.hcpp" at its end then nothing in A.hcpp can be looked up like jump to function definition etc. It works perfectly for A.h file. This kind of file naming is common for templates in c++

A.h

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
  void some_func();
};

#include "A.hcpp" // This will contain some_func which can refer to other classes in the code base
```

The compile_commands.json was generated with the simple "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON".

clangd version I am using is 18.0.0.

Any pointers on what am I missing to get this working will be very helpful

Comment: what is `.hcpp` ?! the standard is either `.c` and `.h` for C files or `.cpp` and `.hpp` for C++ files

Comment: Its a way to extend header more used for templates

Comment: well this industry wide in many large firms and you cannot change a source code when you join a firm according to "standard" ways. Anyway it works in standard IDEs even with these formats. My question is do you know of a way to support it?

Comment: My guess is that `A.hcpp` does not itself include `A.h`, which makes `A.hcpp` not self-contained, which runs into a known limitation with clangd: https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/45

Comment: @HighCommander4 - Thank you. This sounds like the issue - any work arounds? I tried Clion and it works out of the box for the same. Note that A.hcpp cannot include A.h since it will become circular and hence not self-contained as you pointed out.

Comment: @Binu I'm not aware of any workarounds for clangd not supporting self-contained files. CLion uses a heavily patched proprietary fork of clangd; maybe suggest to them that they contribute their solution upstream :) That said, I do think having A.hcpp include A.h should be fine with suitable include guards (the include guard will prevent A.hcpp from including itself recursively if it's opened).

Comment: @HighCommander4 Thank you. Sad that there is no work around. What you said is the case(A.h is included with guards), but I thought about the contents not being included due to the guard and hence my remark - apologies for the confusion :)